# the field $\mathbb{Z}_3[i]$ is ring-isomorphic to the field $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/(x^2 + 1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $\mathbb{Z}_3[i] =${$a+bi | a, b \in \mathbb{Z}_3$} . Show that the field $\mathbb{Z}_3[i]$ is ring-isomorphic to the field $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/(x^2 + 1)$

---

how can I able to do this?can someone help?

Comment: Consider $i \rightarrow x$

Comment: One strategy for problems like this is to use the First Isomorphism Theorem.  Try to find a ring homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$ to $\mathbb{Z}_3[i]$ such that the kernel is the ideal generated by $(x^2+1)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the ring homomorphism

$\mathbb Z_3[x]\rightarrow \mathbb Z_3[i]$ sending $x$ to $i$. This exists by the universal property of polynomial rings. It is clear that no constant or linear polynomial is in the kernel, but $x^2+1$ is. Since $\mathbb Z_3$ is a field, we can use the division algorithm for polynomials to see that any element of the kernel must be a multiple of $x^2+1$. Conversely, all such multiples work. (This is just reiterating the proof of the theorem that a polynomial ring over a field is a PID. You can just quote that theorem if you wish.) So the kernel is the ideal generated by $x^2+1$, and First Isomorphism Theorem for rings gives

$$\frac{\mathbb Z_3[x]}{(x^2+1)} \cong \mathbb Z_3[i].$$

If you need more detail or explanation, just ask. As @Omnivium notes in the comments, this is a very common way of showing two rings are isomorphic.